# umbraco authorization problems

Tags: .net, authorization, umbraco

I inherited an umbraco website from another developer and am having problems with authorization.  The website seems to deny authorization to anonymous users even though I have set authorization to allow users="*".  Is there something else I should be doing in umbraco?

Comment: You should give us some more information, like the exact error message, Umbraco and IIS version; does the problem occur on every page, does the site use the member system to make some pages only available to members, ...

Comment: What membership management are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was file permissions error.  The ACL on the actual directory was restricted but it ended up doing a forms authentication request instead.  I gave everyone permissions to the files and that seemed to have cleared it up.